# how to get values in textboxes based on value selected in drop down list using jsp and mysql

Tags: mysql, jsp

i have a webpage called updategroup.jsp,in this i have one combobox called groupname,i am getting all the available groupnames from database to this drop down box,based on the value selected in dropdown box ,i have to fetch data from database and i should display in text boxes and i need to update mysql table.But my problem is if i select the first combobox value i am getting value whenever i am selecting second value in combobox, in textbaoxes previous values are displaying and the total mysql table is updating. Below is the code for updategroup.jsp:

```
    <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.*"%>
<%
Connection con=null;
String sqlQuery="";
Statement st=null;
ResultSet rs=null;


String groupname_var="";

String data_firstname="";
String data_lastname="";
String data_middlename="";
String data_add1="";
String data_add2="";
String data_city="";
String data_state="";
String data_country="";
int data_zip=0;
String data_phone="";
String data_mn="";
String data_emailid="";
%>
<html>
<head>
<title>edit user</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<style>
td{FONT: 13px Arial,sans-serif;}
th{FONT:bold 13px Arial, sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#153e7e}
input{FONT: 13px Arial,sans-serif;border: solid 1;}
select{font: 13px Arial,sans-serif}
#button{cursor:hand}
A:hover {COLOR: red}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}
 td{
border:none;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function reset()
{
alert("etst");
document.getElementByID("subzone").value="";
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.history.forward();
function noback() { window.history.forward(); }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myoriginaldata()
    {



    document.getElementById("fn").value=document.getElementById("hfn").value;



    document.getElementById("ln").value=document.getElementById("hln").value;



    document.getElementById("mn").value=document.getElementById("hmn").value;



    document.getElementById("add1_id").value=document.getElementById("hadd1").value;



    document.getElementById("add2_id").value=document.getElementById("hadd2").value;



    document.getElementById("city_id").value=document.getElementById("hcity").value;



    document.getElementById("state_id").value=document.getElementById("hstate").value;



    document.getElementById("country_id").value=document.getElementById("hcountry").value;



    document.getElementById("zip_id").value=document.getElementById("hpostalcode").value;



    document.getElementById("phone_id").value=document.getElementById("hphoneno").value;



    document.getElementById("mobile_id").value=document.getElementById("hmobileno").value;



    document.getElementById("email_id").value=document.getElementById("hemailid").value;
    }
</script>

</head>
<form  method="post" name="frm_addUser" action="./updategroup.jsp">
<table width="40%;" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="" bordercolor="#333366" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr><th colspan="2" align="middle"><font size="4">Edit Group</font></th></tr>


<tr>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><font size="4">Group Name</font></td>

<%
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/suwatermeter","root","sumith");
    sqlQuery="select groupname from grouplist";
    st=con.createStatement();

     rs=st.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
%>

<td><select  name="group_name" id="gid" style="WIDTH: 200px" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<option value="">Select groupname</option>
<% while(rs.next()) {%>
<option value="<%=rs.getString("groupname")%>"><%=rs.getString("groupname")%></option>

<% } 

rs.close();
st.close();
con.close();
%>
</td>
</tr>

<%


groupname_var=request.getParameter("group_name");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/suwatermeter","root","sumith");
sqlQuery="select firstname,middlename,lastname,address1,address2,city,state,country,zipcode,phoneno,mobileno,emailid from groupdata where group_name='"+groupname_var+"'";
st=con.createStatement();
rs=st.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
while(rs.next())

{
data_firstname=rs.getString("firstname");
data_lastname=rs.getString("lastname");
data_middlename=rs.getString("middlename");
data_add1=rs.getString("address1");
data_add2=rs.getString("address2");
data_city=rs.getString("city");
data_state=rs.getString("state");
data_country=rs.getString("country");
data_zip=rs.getInt("zipcode");
data_phone=rs.getString("phoneno");
data_mn=rs.getString("mobileno");
data_emailid=rs.getString("emailid");
}
rs.close();
st.close();
con.close();
%>
<input type="hidden" id="hgroupname_id" value="<%=groupname_var%>">
<tr>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><font size="4">First Name </font></td>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><input name="firstname" style="WIDTH: 200px" value="<%=data_firstname%>" id="fn"></td></tr>


<tr>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><font size="4">Middle Name </font></td>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><input name="middlename" style="WIDTH: 200px" value="<%=data_middlename%>" id="mn"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="1" bordercolor="Gainsboro"><font size="4">Last Name </font>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><input name="lastname" style="WIDTH: 200px" type="text" value="<%=data_lastname%>" id="ln">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="1" bordercolor="Gainsboro"><font size="4" color="green"><i>Address</i></font>

</td>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro">

&nbsp;          
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><font size="4">Line 1</font></td>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><input name="lineone" style="WIDTH: 200px" value="<%=data_add1%>" id="add1_id"></td></tr>
<tr>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><font size="4">Line 2</font></td>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><input name="linetwo" style="WIDTH: 200px" value="<%=data_add2%>" id="add2_id"></td></tr>
<tr>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><font size="4">City</font></td>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><input name="city" style="WIDTH: 200px" value="<%=data_city%>" id="city_id"></td></tr>
<tr>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><font size="4">State</font></td>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><input name="state" style="WIDTH: 200px" value="<%=data_state%>" id="state_id"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><font size="4">Country</font></td>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><input name="country" style="WIDTH: 200px" value="<%=data_country%>" id="country_id"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><font size="4">Pin/Zip Code </font></td>
<%
if(data_zip!=0)
      { %>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><input name="postalcode" style="WIDTH: 200px" value="<%=data_zip%>" id="zip_id"></td></tr>
<%
}
%>
<tr>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><font size="4">Phone No</font></td>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><input name="phoneno"  value="<%=data_phone%>" style="WIDTH: 200px" id="phone_id"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><font size="4">Mobile No</font></td>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><input name="mobileno" style="WIDTH: 200px" value="<%=data_mn%>" id="mobile_id"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><font size="4">E-Mail </font></td>
<td bordercolor="Gainsboro"><input name="email" style="WIDTH: 200px" value="<%=data_emailid%>" id="email_id"></td></tr>
<tr>

<td align="center" colspan="2" bordercolor="#f8f8ff">

<input type="submit" value="Update" style="BORDER-RIGHT: green 1px solid; BORDER-TOP:GREEN 1px solid; FONT: GREEN 8pt Tahoma; BORDER-LEFT: GREEN 1px solid; WIDTH: 90px; BORDER-BOTTOM: GREEN 1px solid; HEIGHT: 34px" name="bOk" onclick="return checkInput();">
<input type="reset" value="Cancel" style="BORDER-RIGHT: GREEN 1px solid; BORDER-TOP:GREEN 1px solid; FONT: GREEN 8pt Tahoma; BORDER-LEFT: GREEN 1px solid; WIDTH:90px; BORDER-BOTTOM: GREEN 1px solid; HEIGHT: 34px" name="cancel">

</td></tr>

<%
try
{

String fn_var=request.getParameter("firstname");
String ln_var=request.getParameter("lastname");
String mn_var=request.getParameter("middlename");
String add1_var=request.getParameter("lineone");
String add2_var=request.getParameter("linetwo");
String city_var=request.getParameter("city");
String state_var=request.getParameter("state");
String country_var=request.getParameter("country");
String zipcode_var=request.getParameter("postalcode");
String phone_var=request.getParameter("phoneno");
String mobile_var=request.getParameter("mobileno");
String email_var=request.getParameter("email");

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/suwatermeter","root","sumith");
st=con.createStatement();
%>

<input type="hidden" id="hfn" value="<%=fn_var%>">
<input type="hidden" id="hmn" value="<%=mn_var%>">
<input type="hidden" id="hln" value="<%=ln_var%>">
<input type="hidden" id="hadd1" value="<%=add1_var%>">
<input type="hidden" id="hadd2" value="<%=add2_var%>">
<input type="hidden" id="hcity" value="<%=city_var%>">
<input type="hidden" id="hstate" value="<%=state_var%>">
<input type="hidden" id="hcountry" value="<%=country_var%>">
<input type="hidden" id="hpostalcode" value="<%=zipcode_var%>">
<input type="hidden" id="hphoneno" value="<%=phone_var%>">
<input type="hidden" id="hmobileno" value="<%=mobile_var%>">
<input type="hidden" id="hemailid" value="<%=email_var%>">

<%
if(groupname_var!=null &&  fn_var!=null && mn_var!=null && ln_var!=null && add1_var!=null && add2_var!=null && city_var!=null && state_var!=null && country_var!=null && zipcode_var!=null && phone_var!=null && mobile_var!=null && email_var!=null)
{

if(!groupname_var.equals("") && !fn_var.equals("") && !ln_var.equals("") && !mn_var.equals("") && !add1_var.equals("") && !add2_var.equals("") && !city_var.equals("") && !state_var.equals("") && !country_var.equals("") && !zipcode_var.equals("") && !phone_var.equals("") && !mobile_var.equals("") && !email_var.equals(""))

{
   %>
   <script>
       myoriginaldata();
   </script>
<%

st.executeUpdate("update groupdata set firstname='"+fn_var+"',lastname='"+ln_var+"',middlename='"+mn_var+"',address1='"+add1_var+"',address2='"+add2_var+"',city='"+city_var+"',state='"+state_var+"',country='"+country_var+"',zipcode='"+zipcode_var+"',phoneno='"+phone_var+"',mobileno='"+mobile_var+"',emailid='"+email_var+"' where group_name='"+groupname_var+"'");

}
}

st.close();
con.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
%>
<script>
    document.getElementById("gid").value=document.getElementById("hgroupname_id").value;
</script>

</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
please help me to solve this.
```

Answer (score 0):

hey dont submit your form on onchange event of dropdown list just use call ajax onchange event ...

Comment: thanks for your reply nipun but how to do this with jsp,because i am using jsp

Comment: actually according to mycode i am getting the values in textbox but when ever i am selecting the second value in combo box it is displaying the values of firstcombobox.and the total mysql table is getting updated.